# How to invoke protocol extension default implementation with type constraints

Tags: swift, protocol-extension

Consider the following example:

```
class ManObj {
    func baseFunc() {
        print("ManObj baseFunc")
    }
}

class SubObj: ManObj {
}

protocol Model {
}

extension Model { // This is protocol extension
    func someFunc() { // Protocol extension default implementation
        (self as! ManObj).baseFunc()
        print("Model implementation")
    }
}
extension SubObj: Model {
    func someFunc() {
        print("SubObj Implementation")
    }
}

let list = SubObj()
list.someFunc() // static dispatching

let list2: Model = SubObj()
list2.someFunc() // dynamic dispatching
```

The output is nicely:

```
SubObj Implementation
ManObj baseFunc
Model implementation
```

But I dislike the casting in the line `(self as! ManObj).baseFunc()`.

In fact, I only plan to apply `Model` protocol to subclasses of `ManObj`. (But not all subclasses of `ManObj` are `Model` though!) So, I tried to change `Model` to:

```
extension Model where Self: ManObj {
    func someFunc() {
        self.baseFunc() // No more casting needed!
        print("Model implementation")
    }
}
```

But I'm greeted with error:

`list2.someFunc()` <- `error: 'Model' is not a subtype of 'ManObj'`

So, is there a way for me to trigger `Model.someFunc` from `list2` after I constrain `Model` to `where Self: ManObj`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty class just for type casting

```
class ManObj {
    func baseFunc() {
        print("ManObj baseFunc")
    }
}

class SubObj: ModelCaster {
    func someFunc() {
        print("SubObj Implementation")
    }
}

protocol Model {
}

extension Model where Self: ModelCaster { // This is protocol extension
    func someFunc() { // Protocol extension default implementation
        print("Model implementation")
    }
}

class ModelCaster: ManObj, Model{

}

let list = SubObj()
list.someFunc() //SubObj Implementation

let list2: ModelCaster = SubObj()
list2.someFunc() //Model implementation
```